# twilio error mac : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio'

Tags: python, twilio

First of all, I installed twilio by using command 'sudo pip2 install twilio'. It worked well. But when I test the sample code in IDLE, it shows the following error:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio'
```

I'm using macOS Sierra. I've tried many other things found on forums. There is nothing left so I come here to ask for help guys. Anyways thanks in advance.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError` can only be raised in Python 3.6, so that's what used in IDLE. By using `pip2` you explicitly installed `twilio` in Python 2.x. interpreter. Use `pip3`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it works.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I think this will help others. Do you think you should answer this? Or just close this thread?

Answer (score 0):

`ModuleNotFoundError` can only be raised in Python 3.6, so that's what used in IDLE. By using `pip2` you explicitly installed twilio in Python 2.x. interpreter. Use `pip3` instead.